# Questions about a tcolorbox without a frame

Tags: tcolorbox

I use the package tcolorbox for all my theorems and it works fine.
I also use it for my remarks because I want my remarks numbered with the chapter. The tcolorbox for remarks (unlike my other tcolorbox) are without a frame.
Here is a MWE and the result:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{rem}{Remarque}{%
    enhanced,breakable,colback=white,
    colframe=white,%sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    coltitle=black,boxrule=0pt,
    left=0mm}
    {Remarque}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

Une première phrase.

\medskip
\begin{rem}{}{}
  texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
\end{rem}

Maintenant une remarque entrée à la main.

\medskip

\textbf{Remarque 13.1}

Voici la deuxième remarque.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see just above:

- the remark is not perfectly aligned on the left with the rest of the text.
- the space between the title of the remark and the text of the remark is too big. I would like it to exactly the same as the remark I entered manually (on purpose for this MWE), that is to say baselineskip, I guess

I tried to modify several parameters of the tcolorbox but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 4):

> As you can see just above:
>
> - the remark is not perfectly aligned on the left with the rest of the text.

It's caused by the default setting `boxsep=1mm`. Since `boxsep` is applied to all sides of a `tcolorbox` (just checkout the second figure in package manual, sec. 2 "Quick Reference"), depending on your purpose, either `boxsep=0mm` or `left=-1mm` does the work.

*Edit:* I think use of `oversize` in [samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687722) is better than mine.

*Edit 2:* There're also options `/tcb/blank` and `/tcb/blanker` that  you can have a try.

> - the space between the title of the remark and the text of the remark is too big. I would like it to exactly the same as the remark I entered manually (on purpose for this MWE), that is to say baselineskip, I guess

This is more trickier since setting separations around title and at top won't solve the problem perfectly.  My suggestion is to detach the title then reinsert it before upper part of the box:

```tex
detach title, before upper=\tcbtitle\newline,
```

In total,

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{rem}{Remarque}{%
    enhanced,breakable,colback=white,
    colframe=white,%sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    coltitle=black, boxrule=0pt,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    detach title, before upper=\tcbtitle\newline,
}{Remarque}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

Une première phrase.

\medskip
\begin{rem}{}{}
  Voici la deuxième remarque.
  
  texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
\end{rem}

Maintenant une remarque entrée à la main.

\medskip

\textbf{Remarque 13.1}

Voici la deuxième remarque.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @muzimuzhi Z. It works fine

Comment: In fact, if in my remark, I begin with a \begin{itemize} or {enumerate}, I get an empty line before the first \item. Is there a way to get rid off this first line?

Comment: @Didier Try out `before upper=\tcbtitle\par`?

Comment: Thank you. I’ll try that

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

- to get the text inside of the tcolorbox to align with the surrounding text, you can use the `oversize` option
- there are many ways to adjust the space between the title and the content of the tcolorbox. You could e.g. play with the `top` parameter

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{rem}{Remarque}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    top=-0.8ex,
    oversize
}{Remarque}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

Une première phrase.

\medskip
\begin{rem}{}{}
  Vexte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
\end{rem}

Maintenant une remarque entrée à la main.

\medskip

\textbf{Remarque 13.1}

Voici la deuxième remarque.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @samcarter. It works fine. Just one question: for top=-0.8ex, is it the exact value to have \baselineskip, or is it approximate?

Comment: @Didier Approximated. You can fine tune it if you need it to be more precise.